# Using GitBash Add - Commit - Push file to a GIT repository from WebApplication on Button Click

Tags: asp.net, git, c#-4.0, web-applications, git-bash

I have a requirement where I have to Add - Commit - Push 3 newly created Files into our Git Repository using GitBash commands on Button Click in a Web Application.

I have tried the following but in vain:

```
{
    string gitCommand = "git bash";
    string gitAddArgument = @"add -A" ;
    string gitCommitArgument = @"commit""explanations_of_changes"" ";
    string gitPushArgument = @"push our_remote";

    Process.Start(gitCommand, gitAddArgument );
    Process.Start(gitCommand, gitCommitArgument );
    Process.Start(gitCommand, gitPushArgument );
}
```

On Button Click I need to Call the Git Bash Commands, Commit the 3 Files and then Push to Master Origin.

Comment: AFAIK git bash isn't a command.

Comment: What happens if remote changes?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors within your Git commands..

To add all files use: `git add -A` Note the capital **A**
To commit all modified files with a message use: `git commit -a -m "Your message here"`
To push your changes to remote use `git push`

To make your C# code complete:

```
{
    string gitCommand = "git";
    string gitAddArgument = "add -A" ;
    string commitMessage = "Your commit message";
    string gitCommitArgument = String.Format("commit -a -m \"{0}\"", commitMessage);
    string gitPushArgument = "push";

    Process.Start(gitCommand, gitAddArgument); // Runs: git add -A
    Process.Start(gitCommand, gitCommitArgument); // Runs: git commit -a -m "Your commit message"
    Process.Start(gitCommand, gitPushArgument); // Runs: git push
}
```

## Note

Make sure the program `git` is within your PATH variabele else you wont be able to use it this way. If it's not in your PATH, use the absolute path to the git executeable

For example on linux it would be: `/usr/bin/git` this should be the text for `gitCommand`

Comment: Thanks for the Response....
Since I am using Windows Device, Please explan how do I give Absolute path to Git Bash Executeable.

Comment: Also how would I set the path from where the Files need to be picked and pushed...please respond wrt above

Comment: I think it installs default to: `c:/program files/git/bin/git.exe` Within the installer you could've checked to install it to the path aswell which can be viewed by right clicking "my computer" -> properties -> environment variables

Comment: I tried adding like this : string gitCommand = "/d/Projects/My_ProjectName/Files git";    ..... But it gives an error : The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Then i suppose it's not on that path, did you try wrapping it up in double double quotes?